# Add an image to MKPointAnnotation without changing User Location image

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate, mkpointannotation

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492482/add-a-image-to-mkpointannotation) code to add image to MKPointAnnotation.

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *SFAnnotationIdentifier = @"SFAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView =
    (MKPinAnnotationView *)[_routeMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                         reuseIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
        UIImage *flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BikeIconMap"];
        // You may need to resize the image here.
        annotationView.image = flagImage;
        return annotationView;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

But it is showing the custom image for user location as well. The circular wave animation of user location is also gone.

[image]   [image]

Is there a way to add image to MKPointAnnotation without changing the user location image and animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in the viewForAnnotation: method of MKMapViewDelegate

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) return nil;
```